# Combining two arrays based on the first item in the array

Tags: php

Ok, so I've got two arrays planned - which will be sorted based on a date or timestamp, as so:

```
array([date] => "8/12/12", [rating] => 300)
```

and lets say a second array looks like this:

```
array([date] => "8/12/12", [rating2] => 600)
```

I want to combine these two as such:

```
array([date] => "8/12/12", [rating] => 300, [rating2] => 600)
```

What would be the most effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `+` sign on the array ...

```
$a = array("date" => "8/12/12","rating" => 300);
$b = array("date" => "8/12/12","rating2" => 600);
var_dump($a + $b);
```

Output

```
array
  'date' => string '8/12/12' (length=7)
  'rating' => int 300
  'rating2' => int 600
```

Answer (score 1):

Experiment with `array_merge` and the `+` operator

```
$a = array( 'key' => 'abc', 'foo' => true);
$b = array( 'key' => 'abc', 'bar' => true);
print_r( $a + $b );
print_r( array_merge( $a, $b ) );
```